# Why don't we call migrate just migrate?

Tags: support, migration, close-dialog

I want to flag a question which does not belong on Ask Ubuntu. So I go:

- it should be closed for another reason...
- off-topic because...

but then:

- This is not about Ubuntu. Questions about other Linux distributions
  can be asked on Unix & Linux, those about Windows on Super User,
  those about Apple products on Ask Different and generic programming
  questions on Stack Overflow.

or

- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

There are like 120 Stack Exchange sites, so with a majority of the question I would be inclined to go for the last option because it does not belong on one of the mentioned sites but on an other Stack Exchange site.
However, the last option is to migrate the question instead of closing, and this can only be done to Meta.

After a bit confusion you learn, but maybe we can alter the description a bit to avoid this confusion?

Comment: I think they used "belongs on another site in the SE network" so users wouldn't be confused with the word "migrate". I can't tell you, but I'm pretty sure it was just a plain "migrate" before the new close reasons were put in place..

Comment: We had a few migration paths open, but they got closed. So now the only open path is to [meta].

Comment: Technically a migration seems to work like this: 1. make sure the user have an account on the requested site 2. copy the question to new site 3. close/delete question from here  and don't forget maybe the question is written correctly !? this is a quite complex mechanism, I think is easier to do it manually by the user :)

Comment: @seth and me did discuss this in depth.  Although the conclusion come to write a commented moderator flag.

Comment: Maybe I should have asked "Why don't we remove the migration option and use move to Meta instead?"
However my question was not so much about the option itself but about confusion which the two descriptions could give seen within the same list. For experienced users no problem, they know the options and inexperienced users will just walk into a dead end and probably find the "Not Ubuntu" close option when the other did not work out. But nevertheless it looks confusing to me.